# how to find a hash key with one of the predefined names?

Tags: ruby

I have a hash with an arbitrary key:

```
{'GET': [1,2,3]}
```

or

```
{'POST': ['my data 0', 'my data 1']}
```

The hash is generated from JSON which is sent in the request body. There is just one key, or rather, I ignore any keys but one.

I want to find which key it is, and this is the code that I wrote:

```
items = data['GET'] || data['get'] || data['POST'] || data['post']
```

this does not look neat. If the number of keys that I want to process grows the expression will be long. I want it to be short. I am new to Ruby, is there a better way?

Comment: The hash should be created differently for convenience. `{method: 'POST', data: [1,2,3]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think it might grow, you may want to separate the HTTP methods from the finding of that method in the data:

```
methods = [:get, :post]

def find_method(data)
  keys = methods.map{|m| [m.to_s.upcase, m.to_s]}.flatten
  data.values_at(keys).first
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just get the first value (assuming there's only one) like this:

```
item = data.values.first
```

Comment: thanks. I need to know the key name to dispatch my items to the right method.

Comment: You can use the `.keys` and `.values` methods to get the name of the first key and the value... I'm a bit confused about what you're asking though.

Comment: I do not know what I am asking : ) I am not thinking straight. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Hash#values_at method.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at

```
data.values_at('GET','get', 'POST','post').first
```